# Android AppWidget Vertical Swipe - How

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-gesture, android-remoteview

On the Android developers website, in the section discussing AppWidgets, there is a passage that says that the only available gestures for AppWidgets are touch and vertical swipe ([link)](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/widgets.html):

> Because widgets live on the home screen, they have to co-exist with the navigation that is established there. This limits the gesture support that is available in a widget compared to a full-screen app. While apps for example may support a view pager that allows the user to navigate between screens laterally, that gesture is already taken on the home screen for the purpose of navigating between home panels.
>
> The only gestures available for widgets are:
>
> Touch
>
> Vertical swipe

Does this mean it is possible to listen for vertical swipes on an AppWidget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is meant to say that you can only scroll through a ListView or go through items of the StackView (by doing vertical swipes).

There is no way how to implement regular onScroll, nor onTouch listeners for AppWidget.